# Continuous Scrolling Effect in CSS stopping on first line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a *continuous vertical scroller effect*, however having a couple of issues;

1. The first `line` appears, without stopping, like the rest of the
   line
2. I can't seem to fade-in or fade-out

For the first point, I've tried adjusting the `keyframe` at 0%, too many different options and div heights, but haven't got anywhere.

On the second point, i've tried adding `from: {opacity: 0.5}` and `to: {opacity: 0.5}`, again to no success.

How do I stop the scrolling effect at the first line, like what happens with the subsequent line and add a fade-in fade-out effect?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ekzvLhmx/

**CSS**

```
.tagTextContainer {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdfe5;
}

.tagText {
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.scrollCont {
  font: normal 40px/50px monospace;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 18px;
  top: 0px;
}


.scrollCont .scrollOptions {
  font-size: 13px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  position: relative;

  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /*animation*/
  animation: scroll 10s;
  /*animation-iteration-count*/
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  /*animation-delay*/
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    top: -66px;
  }
  40% {
    top: -116px;
  }
  60% {
    top: -166px;
  }
  80% {
    top: -216px;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="tagTextContainer">
  <span class="tagText">
    Options:
  </span>
  <div class="scrollCont">
      <div class="scrollOptions">
        SJDIUNE92323232<br />
        FHD_231232_FSD<br />
        RUG_12£321231$3<br />
        LA21312321_TQ<br />
        2132131/232 123
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the first item is a little below what you expect.
I modified your version a little [here](https://jsfiddle.net/b5t4gvx7/)

```
<div class="tagTextContainer">
  <span class="tagText">
    Options:
  </span>
  <div class="scrollCont">
      <div class="scrollOptions">
        SJDIUNE92323232<br />
        FHD_231232_FSD<br />
        RUG_12£321231$3<br />
        LA21312321_TQ<br />
        2132131/232 123
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.tagTextContainer {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdfe5;
}

.tagText {
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.scrollCont {
  font: normal 40px/50px monospace;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 18px;
  top: 0px;
}


.scrollCont .scrollOptions {
  font-size: 13px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  position: relative;

  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /*animation*/
  animation: scroll 10s;
  /*animation-iteration-count*/
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  /*animation-delay*/
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  16% {
    top: -15px;
  }
  32% {
    top: -66px;
  }
  48% {
    top: -116px;
  }
  64% {
    top: -166px;
  }
  80% {
    top: -216px;
  }
}
```